# How i can see the image inside UIImageView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

I have an array filled with parsed json data including image url's. But when i try to see that images inside uiimageview, it doesn't the show. What should i do

I printed the url. This is my url inside array.

[image]

This is my array

```
var feedResult = [Result]()
```

It shows the name inside collectionview but i couldn't see the images. I used named like everybody does. But what is missing?

```
let info = feedResult[indexPath.row]
cell.appLabel.text = info.artistName
cell.customCollectionImage.image = UIImage(named: info.artWorkUrl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the image `Data` using the url you got, only then you will use the downloaded data, like so:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(data: downloadedData)
```

Here is a quick subclass of `UIImageView` that does the downloading:

```
class URLImageView: UIImageView {

    func download(url urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (downloadedData, _, error) in
            guard error == nil && downloadedData != nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.image = UIImage(data: downloadedData!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

**Update-1** Use the `download` function using `UIImageView` extension, without subclassing, like so:

```
extension UIImageView {

    func download(url urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (downloadedData, _, error) in
            guard error == nil && downloadedData != nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.image = UIImage(data: downloadedData!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
cell.customCollectionImage.download(url: info.artWorkUrl)
```

Comment: self.image = UIImage(data: downloadedData!) what is image in here?

Comment: `self` refers to `URLImageView` instance

Comment: how can i make it with just function without subclass.

Comment: using an extension, updated the answer, see **Update-1** section

Answer (score 0):

By using `UIImage(named: info.artWorkUrl)` you are not accessing the image in your array but the images in your Assets.xcassets (assets that you add manually in your project).
You need to download the image from the artWorkUrl and then directly use the downloaded image like this:

```
cell.customCollectionImage.image = UIImage(data: yourImageData)
```

Where yourImageData is what you have downloaded from the server with the artWorkUrl.